# How do I route dns traffic through pihole?

Tags: networking, router, dns, mikrotik-routeros, pihole

I have been using my mikrotik with DoH since last year without any issues. So, I recently bought a raspberry pi for the purpose of blocking ads. My previous attempt of blocking ads with scripts in mikrotik doesn't go well. Then if I use unbound as resolver, its fails to resolve some pages and if I use unbound as a forwarder it works. So, to my understanding, my Mikrotik is doing that forwarding with DoH. Which makes unbound as resolver useless. So, is there is a way that I can use that my mikrotik router as a dns server with DoH that I was using before but only ads being removed through the pihole After some search I found this post and implemented this:

```
/ip firewall nat 
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=dns_redirect dst-port=53 in-interface-list=LAN protocol=udp src-address=!192.168.88.5 to-addresses=192.168.88.5 to-ports=53 
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment=dns_redirect dst-address=192.168.88.5 dst-port=53 protocol=udp src-address=192.168.88.0/24 
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=dns_redirect dst-port=53 in-interface-list=LAN protocol=tcp src-address=!192.168.88.5 to-addresses=192.168.88.5 to-ports=53 
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment=dns_redirect dst-address=192.168.88.5 dst-port=53 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.88.0/24
```

Seems, like my router is sometimes able to send queries to the pihole. And then pihole is able to use its own DNS upstream servers to resolve. But, my intention is to redirect piholes traffic to Mikrotik, where in pihole mikrotik will be upstream dns for pihole.So, mikrotik can resolve using DoH. How can I make it work. Something like this:

Client --> Mikrotik-->pihole-->Mikrotik as a DNS over Https--> wan

Comment: Make the DHCP server advertise pihole as the DNS server for the clients?

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Yan pointed out you can cut out the Mikrotik router having ro do hairpin NAT by simply advertising the pihole as DNS server in the DHCP server:

Client --> pihole--> Mikrotik as a DNS over Https--> wan

With Mikrotik routers you can achieve that as follows:

```
/ip dhcp-server network set 0 dns-server=192.168.88.5
```

Make sure to replace `0` with the index of your local network if you have more than one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have some partial success using this:

/ip dhcp-server network 
add address=192.168.88.0/24 dns-server=192.168.88.5 gateway=192.168.88.1 netmask=24 
add address=192.168.88.5 dns-server=192.168.88.1 gateway=192.168.88.1 netmask=24
Now, all traffic routing through pihole. But, the issue is pihole cant use Mikrotik as upstream dns. I didn't add any nat rules yet. Also, google drive, dropbox app having some issues connecting. Currently pihole set to google as upstream dns in its settings.

Comment: Could you please print the DHCP config you have at the moment?
I'm also wondering, why can't you use Mikrotik as upstream DNS and how did you configure that in pihole? this is exactly what I'm doing at home

Comment: /ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.88.0/24 comment=defconf dns-server=192.168.88.5 gateway=\
    192.168.88.1 netmask=24
add address=192.168.88.5/32 dns-server=192.168.88.1 gateway=192.168.88.1 \
    netmask=24

Comment: In pihole, I set custom dns 192.168.88.1. But it breaks the internet. If I set google or any other on pihole then the internet is back again.

Comment: Have you removed the hairpin NAT? If so and you're still having the issues you can send me an email via the address in my profile if you wish to take a look together (to avoid long convos in the comments)

Comment: sent you an email.